# SQL: Return Aggregated Results based on some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with making a conclusion in SQL Server based on some column's values, like status aggregation sort of.
As an example, below is a table containing server tasks and their status.

If I want to return the aggregated status of each server here are the rules:

- if all the server tasks are at status 'SUBMITTED', then the aggregated server status is 'AWAITING'
- if all tasks are at status 'COMPLETED' - the aggregated status is 'DONE'
- if the above cases are not met, the aggregated server status is 'IN PROGRESS'

**Example Table: Tasks**

| Server | Task_Status | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server 1 | RUNNING | 1-1 |
| Server 1 | COMPLETED | 1-2 |
| Server 1 | SUBMITTED | 1-3 |
| Server 2 | COMPLETED | 2-1 |
| Server 2 | COMPLETED | 2-2 |
| Server 3 | SUBMITTED | 3-1 |
| Server 3 | SUBMITTED | 3-2 |

**Example Query Result:**

| Server | Completion |
| --- | --- |
| Server 1 | IN PROGRESS |
| Server 2 | DONE |
| Server 3 | AWAITING |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this:

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT 'Server 1' AS server, 'RUNNING' AS task_status, '1-1' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 1' AS server, 'COMPLETED' AS task_status, '1-2' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 1' AS server, 'SUBMITTED' AS task_status, '1-3' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 2' AS server, 'COMPLETED' AS task_status, '2-1' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 2' AS server, 'COMPLETED' AS task_status, '2-2' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 3' AS server, 'SUBMITTED' AS task_status, '3-1' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 3' AS server, 'SUBMITTED' AS task_status, '3-2' AS task 
)

SELECT server,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT task_status) = 1 AND MAX(task_status) = 'SUBMITTED' THEN 'AWAITING'
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT task_status) = 1 AND MAX(task_status) = 'COMPLETED' THEN 'DONE'
        ELSE 'IN PROGRESS'
    END AS completion
FROM table_name
GROUP BY server
ORDER BY server;
```

Tested in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06912/199)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
select server, 
       case when count(distinct task_status) > 1 then 'in progress' 
            else case min(task_status) 
                   when 'completed' then 'done' 
                   when 'submitted' then 'awaiting' 
                   else 'some other result, perhaps an error' 
                 end 
        end result
  from your_table
group by server
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Server,
  case  max(Task_Status) when 'COMPLETED' then 'DONE' else 
    (case min(Task_Status) when 'SUBMITTED' then 'AWAITING' else 'IN PROGRESS' end )
  end as Completion
from Table_1
group by Server
```

result

```
Server  (Completion)
Server1     IN PROGRESS
Server2     DONE
Server3     AWAITING
```

Comment: I think a complex case statement might be a little cleaner than a nested simple case statement. This also feels a little risky because it is based on alphabetical ordering.

Comment: Yes ideally something like status should be numeric and easily ordered. Status code and its string representation should be in another table. Here fortunately COMPLETED < RUNNING < SUBMITTED.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT 
  server,
  CASE
    WHEN status = 3 THEN 'IN PROGRESS'
    WHEN status = 2 THEN 'WAITING'
    WHEN status = 1 THEN 'DONE'
  END as completion
FROM (
  SELECT
    server,
    MAX( CASE 
       WHEN task_status = 'RUNNING' THEN 3 
       WHEN task_status = 'SUBMITTED' THEN 2 
       WHEN task_status = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1
       END
    ) status
  FROM Tasks
  GROUP BY server
) result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    u.server,
    case 
        when u.cnt=u.cntCompleted then 'DONE'
        when u.cnt=u.cntSubmitted then 'AWAITING'
        else 'IN PROGRESS'
    end Completion
from
(
    select 
        server, 
        count(*) cnt,
        (select count(tstatus) from task t2 where t2.server=t1.server and t2.tstatus='SUBMITTED') cntSubmitted,
        (select count(tstatus) from task t2 where t2.server=t1.server and t2.tstatus='COMPLETED') cntCompleted
    from task t1
    group by server
) u
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pham X Bach for table creation script.

You can go for step by step approach, where you calculate the different statuses count and later apply the logic as given below:

```sql
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT 'Server 1' AS server, 'RUNNING' AS task_status, '1-1' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 1' AS server, 'COMPLETED' AS task_status, '1-2' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 1' AS server, 'SUBMITTED' AS task_status, '1-3' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 2' AS server, 'COMPLETED' AS task_status, '2-1' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 2' AS server, 'COMPLETED' AS task_status, '2-2' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 3' AS server, 'SUBMITTED' AS task_status, '3-1' AS task UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Server 3' AS server, 'SUBMITTED' AS task_status, '3-2' AS task 
)

select server, case when Completed_Count = total_Count then 'Done'
                    when Submitted_Count = total_Count then 'Awaiting'
                    else 'In Progress' end as Completion
from
(
SELECT server, count(case when task_status = 'Completed' then 1 end) as Completed_Count,
count(case when task_status = 'Submitted' then 1 end) as Submitted_Count,
count(*) as total_count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY SERVER
) as t
```

| server | Completion |
| --- | --- |
| Server 1 | In Progress |
| Server 2 | Done |
| Server 3 | Awaiting |